# Missing the middle or a URL

Tags: url

I was wondering if there was a way to find a URL when I am missing the middle. For example, I know that the beginning will be https://welldressedwolf/products/ 
and the end will be pretty-things but I do not know the middle portion.

Comment: Can you give an example that points out what you mean by "middle portion" and and example of the "pretty-things" at the end?

e.g. https://example.com/MIDDLE_PORTION/products/PRETTY_THINGS
where MIDDLE_PORTION is an unknown path, and PRETTY_THINGS is a known page like "myproduct.html"

Comment: Please read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can get the full URL using `window.location.href` 
After that you can remove the parts you dont want and you will have the middle.
More info: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to manually look up the address of a page, you could do so with a google search that specifies the site.

Try a site specific google search using something like the following:
    "pretty things" site:welldressedwolf.com